# Checking for Type `NoneType` fails in randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I'm currently working on function that gets some data from an API and outputs it to csv file. In this function there is a part where I filter the retrieved data before passing it on. Since there is a possibility that the request returns `None` I decided to explicitly check for that and implement a special behavior in this case. Please take a look at the following code snippet.

```
r = requests.post(self.settings['apiurl'],
                  headers=self.settings['header'],
                  json={'query': query_string, 'variables': vars})

jsd = json.loads(r.text)
if jsd is not None:
    lists = jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenres"]
    newlist = [entry for entry in lists if entry["meanScore"] is not None]
    if not newlist:
        return None
    else:
        jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenres"] = newlist
        try:
            jsd = jsd  # json.loads(jsd)
        except ValueError:
            return None
        else:
            return jsd
else:
    return None
```

The `if jsd is not None` part is the before mentioned check. If `jsd` is not `None` I filter again some parts out that I don't need and return a modified version of `jsd`.

The problem now is that I sporadically get the error message:

```
    lists = jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenres"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The first thing that really confuses me is that this error appears completely randomly. In one run it doesn't work on `user_id=7` in the next one it doesn't work on `user_id=8475` but works fine for `user_id=7`, etc.  The second thing that confuses me is that it is even possible for the error to pop up since I explicitly check before accessing the variable if it is of type `NoneType`. Beside from these isolated cases where an error occurs the code produces exactly the results I expect....

I hope I provided you with everything necessary, if not, please let me know. Any kind of suggestions on how to approach this kind of problem are welcome.

Comment: In this subscript sequence `jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenres"]`, one of them could be `None`, maybe not the first one.

Comment: Adding on to @iBug's comment, try printing out individual parts to see what might be `None`. For example, `print (jsd['data'])`, and if this works, proceed with `print (jsd['data']['User'])`, and so on. This shall help you figure out where this issue might be coming from.

Comment: @iBug thanks for suggesting this... I didn't know that the error message was the same no matter the depth.. Certainly useful to know for the future!

Comment: @RachitBhargava Thanks, helped a lot for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly sub-scripting a dictionary is usually fraught with this kind of problem. You should switch to using the [get method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get) on dictionaries. It can handle this case pretty nicely:

```
lists = (jsd.get("data", {}).get("User", {})
         .get("stats", {}).get("favouredGenres", []))
```

Here we exploit the fact that `get()` can take a *default* argument, which it will use if the given key isn't found. In the first 3 cases, we provide an empty dictionary as the default, and we provide an empty list for the last case (since that's what I'm guessing you're expecting).

If you get into the habit of using this accessing method, you'll avoid these kinds of problems.

The [Python Anti-Patterns](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/index.html) book [lists this](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_get_to_return_a_default_value_from_a_dictionary.html) as one to be aware of. The corollary is the [setdefault() call](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_setdefault_to_initialize_a_dictionary.html) when setting values in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting this and especially the website! Seems certainly useful for a newbie like me.